# android DialogFragment savedInstanceState is lost in onCreateView

Tags: android

I have DialogFragment where I want to keep some data on orientation change. In order to do that I have something like that:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState==null) savedInstanceState = new Bundle(); //just in case
    //here I put values to savedInstanceState

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);      
}
```

Next when having:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

I would expect I will get my saved data in savedInstanceState. However it's always(!) null. Why?

Comment: make sure you don't have setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: Have you checked if savedInstanceState is available (i.e. not null) during the onCreate method? I'm usually initialize my state there and have not encountered any problems so far.

Comment: yes setRetainInstance is set to true, however I would expect that then Adnroid will take care about everything. As it doesn't I tried to do it by myself. What setRetainInstance means exactly? I would say that the dialog is not recreated when recreating Activity, but it's not true. For my dialog onCreateView method is executed after recreating the activity. And if I have here setting only default values (initial, user can change them after), the previous state (from user perspective) is lost.

Comment: setting setRetainInstance to false helped, but only partially. As this dialog has the subdialog (child) which is sometimes executed, this child dialog loses callback handler now. Probably because parent dialog is fully recreated. Concluding why when setRetainInstance is set to true, onCreateView is still called when main activity orientation is changed? My feeling is it shouldn't. And is there any possibility to keep setRetainInstance to true but still manage the contents of my own ArrayAdapter connected to list?

Comment: setRetainInstance(true) changes only the onCreate / onDestroy callbacks - they would be called only once. Every other callback associated with the life cycle is unchanged.
Can you post your classes - I got a little confused about what you are persisting in the state Bundle and what not? :)